# Modifying one dimenstional array into two dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a single-dimensional array `$rec = ['123','456','789']` that I would like to modify into an array like:

```
array(
      'id' => 0,
      'addr' => 123,
    ),
array(
      'id' => 0,
      'addr' => 456,
    ),
array(
      'id' => 0,
      'addr' => 789,
    ),
```

To achieve that I have tried looping the original array and inserting each row into the new array like:

```
$rec = ['123','456','789']
$newList = [];
foreach($rec as $i => $r){
  $row = array(
      'id' => $i,
      'addr' => $r,
    );
  $newList = array_combine($newList,$row);
}

return $newList;
```

This results in

```
{
"id": 2,
"addr": "789"
}
```

How do I go about to get what I want?

Comment: Might want to read `array_combine` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine), it doesn't do what you expect. What you need is a simple assignment `$newList[] = ['id' => $i, 'addr' => $r]`.

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja. In all my trials i was forgetting the ```[]``` in ```$newList[]```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rec = ['123','456','789'];

$newArray = [];

foreach($rec as $item) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'id' => 0, // or whatever number you want here
        'addr' => $item,
    ];
}

var_dump($newArray);

Result:
//array (size=3)
//  0 =>
//    array (size=2)
//      'id' => int 0
//      'addr' => string '123' (length=3)
//  1 =>
//    array (size=2)
//      'id' => int 0
//      'addr' => string '456' (length=3)
//  2 =>
//    array (size=2)
//      'id' => int 0
//      'addr' => string '789' (length=3)
```

This can also be done using a for loop(or any other sort of loop for that matter).

---

Using your original idea, we can also achive that:

```
$rec = ['123','456','789'];
$newList = [];
foreach($rec as $i => $r){

    $row = array(
        'id' => $i,
        'addr' => $r,
    );

    $newList[] = array_combine(array_keys($row), array_values($row));
}

var_dump($newList);

Result:
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 0
      'addr' => string '123' (length=3)
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'addr' => string '456' (length=3)
  2 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'addr' => string '789' (length=3)
```

---

Lets take a look at what `array_combine` does

```
/**
 * Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
 * @link https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php
 * @param array $keys <p>
 * Array of keys to be used. Illegal values for key will be
 * converted to string.
 * </p>
 * @param array $values <p>
 * Array of values to be used
 * </p>
 * @return array|false the combined array, false if the number of elements
 * for each array isn't equal or if the arrays are empty.
 * @meta
 */
#[Pure]
function array_combine(array $keys, array $values) { }
```

So you would infact need to get `array_keys` and `array_values` from the `$row` array, also add the new array to the original using `[]`. Which is very redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use array_combine for this purpose

```
$rec = ['123','456','789'];
$newList = [];
foreach($rec as $i => $r){
  $newList[] =  array(
      'id' => 0,
      'addr' => $r,
    );
}

var_dump($newList) ;
```

var_dump Result will be

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["addr"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["addr"]=>
    string(3) "456"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["addr"]=>
    string(3) "789"
  }
}
```

> echo json_encode($newList) ;

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addr": "123"
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addr": "456"
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addr": "789"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$rec = ['123','456','789'];

array_walk($rec, function($value,&$startNum ) use(&$result){
    $result[]=['id'=>$startNum ++,'addr'=>$value];
},);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [addr] => 123 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [addr] => 456 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [addr] => 789 ) )
```